# How can I merge these SQL queries

Tags: mysql

I need to merge this query

```
SELECT 
*,
(SELECT 
        CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname)
    FROM
        wwwpser_customer c
    WHERE
        c.customer_id = o.customer_id) AS customer
FROM
wwwpser_order o
WHERE
o.order_id = '20'
```

with

```
SELECT 
orders . *, wwwpser_comuna.provincia_id AS payment_provincia_id
FROM
wwwpser_order orders
    LEFT JOIN
wwwpser_comuna ON (orders.payment_city = wwwpser_comuna.comuna_id)
```

SQL syntax is new for me so I need a little help with this, thx

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? A `UNION`? Join the two queries? Or find some similar query that somewhat behaves like the combination of the two?

Comment: I need to "add" the second sql select with the first one. It's like the first sql is the original but I need to modify to get the provincia_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this should be your solution.

```
SELECT 
o.*,                                                -- modified (qualified the
(SELECT                                             -- asterisk)
        CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname)
    FROM
        wwwpser_customer c
    WHERE
        c.customer_id = o.customer_id) AS customer, 
c.provincia_id AS payment_provincia_id              -- added from second query
FROM
wwwpser_order o
    LEFT JOIN                                       -- added from second query
wwwpser_comuna c ON (o.payment_city = c.comuna_id)  -- added from second query
WHERE
o.order_id = '20'
```

I strongly recommend learning about the general SQL syntax, though. There are some useful examples in the [MySQL tutorials](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/retrieving-data.html)

Comment: Excellent!!.. And I'm going to follow your advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname)
,      wc.provincia_id 
,      o.*
FROM   wwwpser_order o
LEFT JOIN   
       wwwpser_customer c
ON     c.customer_id = o.customer_id
LEFT JOIN
       wwwpser_comuna wc
ON     wc.comuna_id = o.payment_city
WHERE  o.order_id = 20
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this solution, while looking correct, adds some refactoring to the OP's original query. Given that this is a beginner's question, I think 1-2 comments might be helpful